# Haswell Integrated/NVIDIA Graphics Issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I recently purchased a Lenovo Y510p laptop. The laptop has an NVIDIA GeForce GT750M graphics card. Supposedly the laptop doesn't have integrated graphics but after installing Ubuntu 13.04 and installing the NVIDIA drivers I've discovered that my system is using the integrated graphics instead of the NVIDIA card and no matter what I do I can't seem to get the NVIDIA card activated. I've Googled the heck out of the issue with no success. Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: See here http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all 13.04 is EOL (end of life)

so install another version like 14.04.3 example

then choose to activate an nvidia driver from additional drivers section
like nvidia-340 example + install nvidia-prime + enable performance mode
in nvidia-settings to enable your nvidia card